# Iterate rows and keep value with smaller p-value

Tags: r, loops

Hi I have a data frame in R.
I want to loop through the isoGenes column, and

- if the isoGenes value is repeated, then take the isoGenes with a smaller npval and print out its sid.
- if isoGene value is not repeated, then keep the same sid

So for example in this case, since isoGenes value (ENSG00000001036) in row 1 and 3 is repeated, and isoGenes value (ENSG00000048028) in row 4 and 6 is repeated, the system would change sid value in row 1 & 6 to sid value in row 3 & 4 since they have the smaller npval, and keep all other sid values the same.

```
         isoGenes       npval         sid
1 ENSG00000001036 3.13807e-06 rs116002004
2 ENSG00000002587 2.16743e-07  rs16875728
3 ENSG00000001036 2.93858e-06      rs4279
4 ENSG00000048028 6.55222e-07  rs10891578
5 ENSG00000001460 1.49100e-16   rs1408559
6 ENSG00000048028 7.79798e-07  rs62483619
```

desired output:

```
sid
rs4279
rs16875728
rs4279
rs10891578
rs1408559
rs10891578
```

Would greatly appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a `tidyverse`.

This extracts only the most significant pvalues per Gene.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(isoGenes) %>% 
  top_n(1, -npval)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   isoGenes [4]
  isoGenes           npval sid       
  <chr>              <dbl> <chr>     
1 ENSG00000002587 2.17e- 7 rs16875728
2 ENSG00000001036 2.94e- 6 rs4279    
3 ENSG00000048028 6.55e- 7 rs10891578
4 ENSG00000001460 1.49e-16 rs1408559
```

and this gives your expected output.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(isoGenes) %>% 
  mutate(sid = sid[which.min(npval)]) 
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   isoGenes [4]
  isoGenes           npval sid       
  <chr>              <dbl> <chr>     
1 ENSG00000001036 3.14e- 6 rs4279    
2 ENSG00000002587 2.17e- 7 rs16875728
3 ENSG00000001036 2.94e- 6 rs4279    
4 ENSG00000048028 6.55e- 7 rs10891578
5 ENSG00000001460 1.49e-16 rs1408559 
6 ENSG00000048028 7.80e- 7 rs10891578
```

add `ungroup() %>% select(sid)` to get onyl the rsid column.

Comment: wow, thank you so much that worked! really appreciate it :)